# Spyder not working with Anaconda "An error ocurred while starting the kernel"

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to use a fresh installation of Anaconda with python 3.8.8 on Windows10 and (as the title says) I cannot get Spyder to start a kernel.  Actually, when I initially installed anaconda and opened Spyder it could start.  Then, I added an environment, and changed preferences to use that environment, and then if stopped being able to start.

There is no traceback, just a red bar saying "An error ocurred while starting the kernel", then

```
Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right 
version of it installed (>= 1.9.4 and < 1.10.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to 
create a console for you.

You can install it by running in a system terminal:
conda install spyder‑kernels
```

I did run that, and other things like updating iPython and conda update all, and running Spyder as and admin, but nothing helps.  Neither do any of the instructions I could find.

I never had these problems with WinPython, and my guess is there is some configuration regarding environments that I haven't gotten right.  So what do I need to change for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause for the error is that the currently recommended download package for Anaconda 3.8 does not come with the newest version of Spyder.  I had Spyder v4.1.5, which according to [Spyders' common problems page](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/common-illnesses.html) requires v1.9.4 of spyder‑kernels.  Installing that version of spyder-kernels fixed the problem.